# Android Studio Emulator "Obtaining IP Adress" While trying to Connect to WIFI

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-wifi

[Image to the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17wBc.png)

Im trying to connect the avd to internet via WIFI and it's making this weird error every time I try to connect to the default network in the avd **"AndroidWifi"**

After a bit of searching and trying to fix it
I found out that the error is happening because it cannot get the AVD's IP Address

so I tried changing it with the "Advanced Settings" in the **"AndroidWifi"** Modify tap by making it the ipv4 for my laptop

it connected to the network successfully but it says "connected, no internet"

I have been trying to fix this error for 2 days now I hope that you guys can help me

Comment: I have the same issue on my machine, did you find out anything? Always trying to reconnect, never establishes a wifi connection.

Answer (score 0):

To have an active internet connection, switch off emulator WIFI and switch on the Mobile data.